# Inconsistent behavior while executing batch file from java

Tags: java, batch-file, runtime.exec

Our java method executes a batch script as below:

```
String command = batchFilePath + File.separator + filename + " " + path;
logger.info("Command to be executed = " + command);
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
logger.info("Batchfile execution has started");
```

We have encountered a situation wherein the batch file execution did not happen. However both the logger statements before and after has been properly logged. Also the above snippet is within try catch block and we see that there were no exceptions recorded in the logs. The batch file executes another .exe file and the output of that is written to a separate file and this file was not generated either. In the batchfile we have logger statements incase the .exe execution is a failure but no error there as well.

Could someone help us identify why the batch file execution did not happen as we do not see any errors or exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

[This explains how to capture error and output for a started thread](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html?page=2)

You can use `process.getErrorStream()` to get the error response from your process.

And you can create a thread to constantly read from that error stream, like this:

```
static class StreamGobbler extends Thread {
    InputStream is;
    String type;

    StreamGobbler(InputStream is, String type){
        this.is = is;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String line=null;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
                System.out.println(type + ">" + line);    
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();  
            }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){

     String command = batchFilePath + File.separator + filename + " " + path;
     logger.info("Command to be executed = " + command);
     Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
     logger.info("Batchfile execution has started");

     StreamGobbler errorGobbler = new StreamGobbler(proc.getErrorStream(), "ERROR");
     errorGobbler.start();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Gagan, xtratic Ok, i'l add above mentioned logic to my code to look for any error. To mention, strange part is that it get executed fine if we re-run it without making any changes to the command or input.

Comment: yes i did try this. but we are running into some memory issue. we are checking whether its related or something else is causing it. And its not me who downvoted this.